# React-Learflet - Change circle opacity when clicked

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3, react-leaflet-v4

I'm trying to change my circle Opacity when I click on it to act as an active state

I declared my state

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
```

My function

```
  const sidebarTrigger = () => {
    setActive(true)
  }
```

this is how i'm trying to change it, inside my **MapContainer**

```
fillOpacity= {active ? '0.9' : '0.7'}
```

**MapContainer**

```
  <MapContainer whenCreated={setMap}  center={[selectedRegion['lat'],selectedRegion['long']]} zoom={selectedRegion['zoom']} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            {props.regionC.map((item,i) =>  {
                <Circle 
                  eventHandlers={{ click: sidebarTrigger.bind(this, item.city,item.lat,item.long) }}
                  center={item.city === 'Johannesburg'  || item.city === 'Johhensburg' ? [-26.195246,28.034088] : [item.lat ,item.long]}
                  color= '#EE7E18'
                  fillColor="#EE7E18" 
                  fillOpacity= {active ? '0.9' : '0.7'}
                  weight="0"
                  radius={radius}
                />
                )
            }

             })}
        </MapContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [React Leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#props) state that the props of child components are immutable:

> By default these props should be treated as immutable, only the props explicitely documented as mutable in this page will affect the Leaflet element when changed.

so this explains why the opacity of the `<Circle>` does not update when you change the value of `active`.

If you use a ref, this will allow you to perform operations on the Circle. In the code below, we get a ref to the `<Circle>` and the `click` event handler calls `updateActiveState()` which updates the value of the active state:

```
const circleRef = useRef();

const updateActiveState = () => {
  setActive((prevState) => !prevState);
};
...

<Circle
  eventHandlers={{
    click: () => {
      updateActiveState();
    },
  }}
  ...
  fillOpacity={active ? '0.9' : '0.5'}
  ...
  ref={(ref) => {
    circleRef.current = ref;
  }}
/>
```

You can then define an effect that calls Leaflet's [setStyle](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle-setstyle) method to update the `fillOpacity` of the Circle based on the value of `active`. This will be executed whenever the value of `active` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (circleRef.current) {
    circleRef.current.setStyle({ fillOpacity: active ? '0.9' : '0.5' });
  }
}, [active]);
```

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-bmsmtj?file=Map.tsx) for a working demo.